# Include a PDF, but not on a separate page

Tags: pdf

Is there anyway to include a pdf, that doesnt move it to a new page?

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\section{Laster}

\includepdf[width=18cm,pages={1-},pagecommand={}]{Billeder/Vindlastberegninger.pdf}


\end{document}
```

With this code, the section "Laster" will have its own separate page. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: use `pagecommand={\section{Laster}}`

Comment: Then don't use `\includepdf` it will always create new pages. You can try with the regular `\includegraphics`

Comment: @daleif yes, but its tedious to add 10-15 pages of excel.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer - that works, but it adds the comment on every page. Is there a way to add the command only on the first page?

Comment: split the command in `\includepdf[width=18cm,pages=1,pagecommand={\section{xxx}}]` and `\includepdf[width=18cm,pages={2-},pagecommand={}]`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!